# Cyclist coasting on a plane road (only air resistance and rolling resistance apply)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, drag

I am currently trying to simulate a cyclist. Right now I am looking at the change of velocity when the cyclist is coasting on a plane road. These are the values I am using:

```
Weight of cyclist and bike: 93kg

coefficient of rolling resistance: 0.004

coefficient of air resistance: 0.490 ( frontalSurface 0.4 * dragCoefficient 1 * airDensity 1.225)
```

---

```
I assume rollingResistance = coefficientRollingResistance * mass * 9.81

I assume airResistance = (coefficientOfAirResistance * velocity^2) / 2
```

---

With these I get the following:

Coasting down from an initial velocity of 25 km/h will take 94 seconds until cyclist comes to complete stop.

---

This value of 94 seconds until coming to a complete stop seems rather long. Is it plausible?

At 25 km/h I have calculated an air resistance of 12N

At 5 km/h air resistance is down to 0.5N

Rolling Resistance is constant at 3.6N

All in all 94 seconds seems a bit long and it does not really match up with practical experience when cycling...

---

**Now my question is:** Are my calculations correct, or where did I go wrong?

Comment: :-) I have implemented it in such a way that the simulation stops once the velocity is zero or less :-)

Comment: D'Oh! It seems that there is less difference between static friction and kinetic friction than I remembered. I have retracted my previous comment.